# LeftMenu disappears with DNN Version 9.1 upgrade

Tags: dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-9

I'm using DNN Evoq Basic Version 9.1. I recently upgraded from Version 8.5. Upon upgrading, one of our website's left menu navigation has disappeared.

We are using the following code in our `.ascx` file:

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="dnn" TagName="LEFTMENU" Src="~/Admin/Skins/leftmenu.ascx" %>
<dnn:LEFTMENU runat="server" EnableAdminMenus="true" ID="LM" />
```

I traced the source file and it still exists in the file structure. Is this code still valid in Version 9.1? If so, how do I make it work again?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jennifer,

I haven't found anything definitive by Googling, but I did look at the source for an older version.  The file LeftMenu.ascx.cs references the Telerik.Web.UI.

As Telerik components are being removed from DNN, and DNN 9.1 was a breaking point with most of the Telerik components being replaced, I'd be willing to bet that the LeftMenu is no longer part of DNN.  If you review the discussion leading to DNN 9.1, you'll see lots of references to this and to breaking changes related to Telerik.

That's the bad news.  The good news is that you should be able to replace the LeftMenu with an instance of DDRMenu and some appropriate CSS styling.

Feel free to ask me for more details if that would help, or point me to the older version of the site -- if that's still possible.

Comment: It appears that you're correct. I opened up a support ticket with DNN and they have said that they're phasing out any Telerik references in their CMS. In that case, anything that has `Rad....` prefixed to it, like a `RadComboBox` or `RadTextEditor` will also disappear with the newer versions of DNN. Certainly bad news, but we have other methods to develop these pieces, as you have mentioned. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Just for anyone that is encountering this problem, DNN has officially notified us via our support ticket that the LeftMenu option will be deprecated with the unveiling of newer versions of DNN. We ended up rewriting a new menu using the DDRMenu that takes on a newer UI and our custom code.